# Error: permission_denied at /items: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data

Tags: firebase, ember.js, ember-data, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I can neither receive nor write data in the Cloud Firestore (Firebase). I do everything in an application based on Ember.

In the file **config/environment.js** were added all the data from the "console" Firebase.

I also changed the access rules for testing:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to retrieve the data:

```
model () {
  return this.store.findAll('item')
  // or
  // return this.store.query('project', { orderBy: 'title' })
}
```

I'm getting errors:

```
Error while processing route: index – "permission_denied at /items: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data."
```

And:

```
Error: permission_denied at /items: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Based on the GitHub issue here: https://github.com/simplyaccessible/angular-a11y-ticket-tracker/issues/1 this error definitely looks like an issue with your firebase permissions rules, not anything with Ember. Although your default open access rule for testing also looks exactly how it does in the relevant docs. Is it possible your testing rule is not getting deployed correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify firebase rules :

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true"
  }
}
```